# Disable Scroll bar for smooth scrolling website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently developing the frontend of a website which is single page with smooth scrolling between divs.

I want to disable scrolling by mouse itself.

I know `overflow:hidden;` removes the scroll bars, however, I want the page to scroll only when they click on the link to the required div. What is the correct way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',wheel,false);
}

function wheel(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue=false;
}
window.onmousewheel=document.onmousewheel=wheel;
</script>
```